# How to use my own sikuli file in java application

Tags: java, sikuli

I have sikuli file which defined some classes in it.
What I want to do is to use these classes in my own java program.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Have you looked in [Sikulis FAQ - How to use Sikuli Script in your JAVA programs](http://sikuli.org/docx/faq/030-java-dev.html)?

Comment: yes, but what Sikuli document tells us is how we can use sikuli api in java program. And we know that Sikuli is writern with java . What I mean here is that I have a sikuli file . And I want to use the classes defined in sikuli file directly in java program. I think It's total diferent cases

Answer (score 0):

Look at the files in a working Sikuli directory ie HelloWorld.sikuli.  Sikuli scripts are written in jython, not java.  A technicality, but it is important to understand that your Sikuli file is a .py not a .java.  The directory will also contain a .class file which is the compiled Jython machine code.  The reference [here](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html) shows how to use jython in java.